# What happens at the end of git reset --hard?

Tags: git

We are using `git reset --hard` at the end of our builds to make sure things stay clean, and the output looks kind of like this (we insert the time stamps to enable debugging):

```
2022-10-05 16:54:39,380 Updating files:   0% (116/52369)
2022-10-05 16:56:12,543 Updating files: 100% (52369/52369), done.
2022-10-05 17:15:41,768 HEAD is now at baf5396ee94dea7
```

I have seen that the time going from 0-100% remains about the same always at 1.5 minutes.
When I profiled git I found the time was spend doing getfileattrib calls.  However, the time going from "done" to "HEAD is now at"  can take a wide range of time.  The median time is 5 minutes, and the 95th percentile is 18 minutes.  Does anyone know what git is doing that it could take that long?  I don't have pdbs for git (if anyone could point me to where they are that would be great), so I can't actually use the profile I have at this point.

Comment: The CI system, which is on a remote datacenter server.  C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe reset --hard HEAD

Comment: I think the reason is so that if any build processes happen to accidentally modify the source state, that it gets fixed appropriately.  We don't want anyone to do this, but it is hard to verifiably prevent every build task from doing this for every build.

Answer (score 0):

Once `git reset --hard` has finished updating the set of working files, it must finish updating Git's index. This normally goes very fast.  However, depending on whether you're using the split index mode and have cached trees in the index, it may have to do a bit more work than usual.

Even then this *should* go very quickly, relative to how long it takes to march through a tree of files.  It seems likely that your service provider has noticed that your VM is using a lot of system resources, and has deliberately slowed down the "clock" in your builder.  Or to put it more colorfully, your builder is now being punished for its earlier sins.

Comment: Assuming no files were changed, the index would not be updated right?

Comment: It still gets rewritten, even if no files changed, although there *might* be some early exit path (I didn't spot it in a quick scan).